# MySQL Syntax error for 5.6.17_1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL `5.6.17_1` and have query that is used for `5.1.xx`

```
select
    schtermid,idfptnsubid,d.idfptnid,idflinksetid,
     cast(count(distinct cthr) as real)/cast(count(distinct s.schid)  as real)*100  as ctr, cast(sum(status) as real)/cast(count(*) as real)*100  as pfiled,
 count(distinct s.schid)  as schcount
from source.kdm_session as
```

This complains

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

```
'real)/cast(count(distinct s.schid)  as real)*100  as ctr, cast(sum(status) as' at line 3
```

Which part is wrong? What should I change to get the same thing to happen?

Comment: Is that your full query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [per the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast), `real` is not a valid type:

> The type for the result can be one of the following values:
>
> ```
> BINARY[(N)]
> CHAR[(N)]
> DATE
> DATETIME
> DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
> SIGNED [INTEGER]
> TIME
> UNSIGNED [INTEGER]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your calcs:

```
(count(distinct cthr) * 1.0)/(count(distinct s.schid) * 1.0)*100  as ctr,
(sum(status) * 1.0)/(count(*) * 1.0)*100  as pfiled,
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a mess - you are mixing up the arguments and inventing types. You're also *trying* to use AS both as a seperator within a call to CAST() and as an alias operator. Since its meaning is contextual it's good practice not to mix and match in the same query.

Formatting part of your query...

```
cast(
    count(distinct cthr) as real)
    / cast(
       count(distinct s.schid)  as real
    )*100  as ctr
    , cast(sum(status) as real)
        /cast(count(*) as real)*100  as pfiled
```

Sorry - but this is so messed up I haven't a clue what you are trying to do here. You seem to be trying the cast the result of a calulation to a type defined by the result of another calculation. Since the can't all have the same alias I guess you must think that 'real' is a type in MySQL (it isn't). Even if you meant a floatling point number - this is just silly - the result of a count is always an integer. You don't even have the same number of opening and closing brackets.

In addition to NOT using 'AS' within CAST(), and using the valid MySQL types, if you formatted your quesry better and provided examples of inputs and outputs we might have a chance at helping you.